# An example of a non-trivial primary polynomial

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

An ideal $I \leq R$ is called **primary** if $\forall ab\in I$ than either $a\in I$ or $b^n \in I$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. A polynomial $p(x)$ is called **primary** if the ideal $(p(x)) \leq R[x]$ is primary.

Trivial example: $(x^2) \leq R[x]$ or $(q^n(x)) \leq R[x]$ for an irreducible polynomial $q(x)$, are primary ideals.

I believe that when $R$ is a field (or even UFD) all primary polynomials are of the form $q^n(x) \in R[x]$ for an irreducible polynomial $q(x)$ due to unique factorization. However, I am concerned with the case where $R=\mathbb{Z}_{p^s}$. Due to some theorem* I know the following should be examples of primary polynomials,

$(x^2+x+1)(x^2+3x+1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^2}$ or even $(3x+1)(x+1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2^2}$ is supposedly an example.

However, I fail to see why these examples work or with rough terms how can a nontrivial example of a **primary** polynomial can occur?

*Aforementioned theorem: For $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^s}$ if $\overline{f(x)} = g^n(x)$ where $\overline{f(x)} , g(x) \in \mathbb{F}_p(x)$ and $g(x)$ is irreducible then $f(x)$ is primary. (overline denoted the image of f(x) in the quotient $\mathbb{Z}_{p^s}/(p) \cong \mathbb{F}_p$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to take your second example, in $\Bbb Z_4$, we have
$$
(3x+1)(x+1) = (1-x)(1+x) = 1-x^2
$$
This is a non-trivial primary polynomial because it's reducible, and not the power of an irreducible polynomial, but the ideal $(1-x^2)$ is a primary ideal. For instance, $(1-x)(1+x)$ is contained in the ideal, but neither of the factors are in the ideal. However,
$$
(1-x)^4 = 1-2x^2+x^4 = (1-x^2)^2
$$
is an element of the ideal.

Comment: Litreally the same seem to do the trick for the other example. If I am not mistaken we have ;
$(x^2+x+1)^4 = (x^2+x+1)^2 (x^2+3x+1)^2 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

I wonder if this is coincidental or is there a deeper truth.
cf: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+1)%5E4+expanded+form
and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2+%2B+x+%2B+1)%5E2+(x%5E2+%2B3x+%2B+1)%5E2+++expanded+form

Comment: @BaranZadeoglu You mean that in both cases we seem to have $f(x)^4 = (f(x)g(x))^2$? I think that's coincidental, although the even powers make many of the coefficients even, which means they are likely to disappear in $\Bbb Z_4$, and for those that don't disappear, sign becomes irrelevant. That ought to make it easier for different products and powers to coincide..

Comment: Further empirical results:
$(x^2 +x+1)^4(x^2 +7x+1)^4 \equiv (x^2 +x+1)^8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8$
cf:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialMod%5B(x%5E2+%2Bx%2B1)%5E4(x%5E2+%2B7x%2B1)%5E4,8%5D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialMod%5B(x%5E2+%2Bx%2B1)%5E8,8%5D
and
$(x^3 +2x+1)^9(x^3 +5x+1)^9 \equiv (x^3 +2x+1)^ {18}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{27}$
cf:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialMod%5B(x%5E3+%2B2x%2B1)%5E9(x%5E3+%2B5x%2B1)%5E9,27%5D
and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolynomialMod%5B(x%5E3+%2B2x%2B1)%5E18,27%5D
I think there might a deeper truth.

Comment: Hmm... $(1+x)^2=(1-x)^2$ in $\Bbb Z_4$. Yeah, there might be something the.

Comment: @Arthur: I don't follow how your argument shows that for $R=\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$, the ideal $I=(1-x^2)$ of $R$ is a primary ideal. Don't you have to show that _whenever_ $a,b\in R$ are such that $ab\in I$, then $a\in I$ or $b^n\in I$, for some positive integer $n$?

Comment: @quasi Yes. It was an example demonstrating the primary-ness of the ideal, not a full proof. You can see that from how I write "For instance" in front of it.

Comment: @Arthur: So how would a full proof proceed?

Comment: @quasi If I were to prove it, I would begin by attempting to prove that $ab\in \langle x^2-1\rangle$ implies that either $a$ or $b$ is divisible by either $1-x$ or $1+x$. And since $(1-x)^4 = (1+x)^4\in \langle 1-x^2\rangle$, we would be done. If that didn't work out, I would have to think of something else.

Comment: @Arthur: Well, you have $2\cdot 2\in (1-x^2)$ and $2$ is not divisible by $1-x$ or $1+x$. But assuming $ab\in (x^2-1)$ and $ab\ne 0$, your suggested approach seems like a good plan of attack. However I don't see an immediate way to implement the plan.

Answer (score 1):

From the text

> $\;\;\;$Atiyah & MacDonald -- Introduction to Commutative Algebra (1969), page 51

we have the following theorem:

> $\;\;\;$Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$.
>
> $\;\;\;$If $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $\text{rad}(I)$ is maximal, then $I$ is primary.

Now let $R=\mathbb{Z}_4[x]$.

First, consider the ideal $I=\bigl((3x+1)(x+1)\bigr)$.

To show that $I$ is primary, we can argue as follows . . .

Since $(3x+1)(x+1)=(1-x)(1+x)=1-x^2$ is a non-unit, $I\ne (1)$, hence $\text{rad}(I)\ne (1)$.
$\\[8pt]$
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&2^2=0\in I\\[4pt] 
\implies\;&2\in\text{rad}(I)\\[12pt]
\text{so}\;\;&1-x^2\in I\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-x^2\in\text{rad}(I)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-x^2+(2x^2)\in\text{rad}(I)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1+x^2\in\text{rad}(I)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1+2x+x^2\in\text{rad}(I)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(1+x)^2\in\text{rad}(I)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1+x\in\text{rad}(I)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $(2,1+x)\subseteq \text{rad}(I)$.

But the ideal $(2,1+x)$ is maximal in $R$, since
$$
\mathbb{Z}_4[x]/(2,1+x)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(1+x)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2
$$
which is a field.

Thus, $\text{rad}(I)$ is maximal, hence $I$ is primary.

Next, consider the ideal $J=(fg)$, where 
$$
\begin{cases}
f=x^2+x+1\\[4pt]
g=x^2+3x+1=x^2-x+1\\
\end{cases}
$$
To show that $J$ is primary, we can argue as follows . . .

Since $fg=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^4+x^2+1$ is a non-unit, $J\ne (1)$, hence $\text{rad}(J)\ne (1)$.
$\\[8pt]$
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&2^2=0\in J\\[4pt] 
\implies\;&2\in\text{rad}(J)\\[12pt]
\text{Also}\;\;&(f+g)(f-g)=(2x^2+2)(2x)=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f^2=g^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f^3=fg^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f^3\in J\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f\in\text{rad}(J)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $(2,x^2+x+1)\subseteq \text{rad}(J)$.

But the ideal $(2,x^2+x+1)$ is maximal in $R$, since
$$
\mathbb{Z}_4[x]/(2,x^2+x+1)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)
$$
which is a field.

Thus, $\text{rad}(J)$ is maximal, hence $J$ is primary.